# I need some clarification regarding Big O

Tags: java

I have a few questions so please bear with me.  I need some help to clarify Big O and run time.  As I understand it Big O is a way of presenting the run time of an algorithm correct?  From reading I've been trying to figure out how to calculate the Big O of an algorithm.  So far I've figured out that something like this has a Big O of O(N^2)

```
for(i = 0; i < N, i++)
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
      //code
```

But what happens if it is this:

```
for(i = 0; i < N, i++)
    for(j = 0; j < M; j++)
      //code
```

Where N isnt always equal to M.

Also what is the Big O if you have two of these added together?

```
for(i = 0; i < N, i++)
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
      //code
for(i = 0; i < N, i++)
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
      //code
```

Is the big O equal to N^2 + N^2 = 2N^2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where N isnt always equal to M.

Then it is `O(NM)`, unless `M` is dependent on `N` or vice versa.  If they are independent, then it is also true to say that it is `O(N)` and `O(M)`.

> Is the big O equal to N^2 + N^2 = 2N^2?

`O(2N^2)` is equivalent to `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're correct. For the second one it would O(N*M). For the third one you are right as well but that can reduce from O(N^2 + N^2)=O(2*N^2)=O(N^2).

Big oh notation is used for approximating the run time of the algorithm. So in this case the multiplication factor of 2 is not nearly as great as the power coefficient and so we get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

The second example is O(N * M).  The third is still O(N^2), because a constant factor (2) doesn't change the BigO. What counts is that if you double N, the time is multiplied by 4. If you triple N, the time is multiplied by 9.

Answer (score 0):

For the first two cases, realize that Big-O is just a function of two variables in this case.  If I told you `f(x,y) = x + sin y` would you say that f(x) = `f(x) + sin x`?  No, that's nonsense.

It really is `O(N*M)`.  If you're in a situation where M is a fixed constant and you're interested in how your program will perform in terms of N, then it's linear in N or `O(N)`.  But sometimes you're in situations where you know N=M, say you're dealing with a square, in which you could say the function is `O(N^2)`.  But without any constraints like `M=k` for some konstant k or `M=N`, the only accurate thing to say is `O(N*M)`.  If you tell me that's quadratic then I will reverse engineer and expect N=M or something, and if you tell me it's linear I will expect one to be held constant.

If you want to get more theoretical with it, you could just note that saying `O(something)` is always nonsense until you specify the variables you're working in.  `f(N,M) = NM` is `O(N) w.r.t. N`, `O(NM) w.r.t N,M` and `O(N^2) w.r.t N where M=N`.

If you want to get more mathy...  that's wikipedia or math.stackexchange.com :)